# SonarQube: How to configure fallback authentication when using Crowd

Tags: sonarqube, atlassian-crowd

Sonar supports fallback to the built-in authentication when using LDAP authentication. I expect the same to work for Crowd but somehow this does not seem to be the case. Is this a bug or do I miss some setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the logs - is there an uncaught exception being thrown for failed Crowd authentication attempts? The `CrowdAuthenticator` may need to be fixed to catch them to and return `false` rather than propagating.

[SONAR-3138](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3138) appears to have implemented general fallback for all external authentication providers, although there was a [fix required](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/changelog/sonar-plugins/?cs=5110) for the LDAP provider to allow fallback to work. Assuming you're using [sonar-crowd-plugin's `CrowdAuthenticator.java`](http://svn.codehaus.org/sonar-plugins/tags/sonar-crowd-plugin-1.0/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/crowd/CrowdAuthenticator.java) it's possible that a similar bug remains in the Crowd authenticator.

Edit: the LDAP authenticator also has [a full `SecurityRealm`](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-ldap/blob/8591b66ac19cf998832bd5926d906e3258cdf527/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/ldap/LdapRealm.java). This may be necessary to get the fallback behaviour when a user doesn't pass authentication.

Comment: There is an exception  (com.atlassian.crowd.integration.exception.InvalidAuthenticationException) and I suspected that it simply is a bug. I could solve my current problem though by creating the user in an internal Crowd directory.